# GeoServer meta-tile configuration

Tags: openlayers

Can someone point me in the right direction? Somewhat new to GIS / GeoServer. I'm attempting to configure meta-tiling on GeoserverWebCache as described [here](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/concepts/metatiles.html). We've run into the duplicate label problem with out vector tiles. Currently we make requests in the following way :

```
uriBuilder
.path("/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/{layerName}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.{format}").build("search:$layerName@EPSG%3A900913@pbf", zoom, x, y, format)
```

Geoserver logs return the following :

[image: Logs from Geoserver]

The documentation states that we need to set `tiled=true`. My question is, how would I alter the above get request to set the tiled parameter?

**What I've tried**

I've attempted [the following solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309890/how-to-pass-viewparams-with-vector-tile-request-using-open-layers-5) by changing the request like so :

```
http://localhost:8089/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=landonline-search:all_parcels&STYLE=&FORMAT=application%2Fvnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL=31947&TILEROW=11777&VIEWPARAMS=ispercent:1;R:0000FF;zoomlevel:15&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:15&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326
```

GeoServer then returns with the following error :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: Coordinates out of bounds in ST_GeomFromText.
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.runQuery(JDBCFeatureReader.java:282)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.<init>(JDBCFeatureReader.java:153)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:620)
        ... 145 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Coordinates out of bounds in ST_GeomFromText.
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.addException(IfxSqli.java:3129)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3394)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2292)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2217)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeStatementQuery(IfxSqli.java:1461)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.executeQuery(IfxResultSet.java:183)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeQueryImpl(IfxStatement.java:968)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeQuery(IfxStatement.java:165)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.lambda$new$0(JDBCFeatureReader.java:153)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.runQuery(JDBCFeatureReader.java:271)
```

**UPDATE :**
This is an example of the duplicate label probem we're encoutering.
[image]

Comment: There's no need for a tiled parameter in a wmts request. But metatiling won't solve your label problem (or the one you show) you need to provide a fixed location for the label and set the vendor option partials to true.

Comment: @IanTurton, I've updated the question with an example of the issue.

Comment: That is not related to the error,

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37196/79

Comment: Thanks but that link is styling it on the server, which is not an option. I need to do this within Openlayers @IanTurton

Comment: OK, I've updated your tags fro the question to reflect where the issue is